# how to rbind/append data.frames from a list together and drop duplicates

Tags: r

I have a list that contain multiple data.frame with same name setting. I would like to combine them together in to one data.frame and adrop the duplicates. how can I do that?

sample data can be build using codes:

```
lst1 <- list(data1 = mpg, data2 = mpg, data3 = mpg)
```

The results will be `mpg`.

sth like:

[image]

Many thanks.

Comment: Maybe `unique(do.call(rbind, lst1))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this. You can create an id for each dataframe in the list and after binding you can exclude the duplicated values:

```
library(dplyr)
#Data
lst1 <- list(data1 = mpg, data2 = mpg, data3 = mpg)
lst1 <- lapply(lst1, function(x) {x$id<-1:nrow(x);return(x)})
#Bind
df <- do.call(bind_rows,lst1)
df2 <- df[!duplicated(df$id),]
df2$id <- NULL
```

**Update:** To keep data source:

```
library(dplyr)
#Data
lst1 <- list(data1 = mpg, data2 = mpg, data3 = mpg)
lst1 <- lapply(lst1, function(x) {x$id<-1:nrow(x);return(x)})
#Bind
df <- bind_rows(lst1,.id = 'data')
df2 <- df[!duplicated(df$id),]
df2$id <- NULL
```

Comment: Thanks. what if I want to retain the data source info in the final df? such as that variable is from data1, data2? I updated post. so I would like to add col to keep the data source info

Comment: @Stataq I believe I can add and id variable!

Comment: @Stataq Please check the `df2` and `df` with last code, there is a new variable called data.

Comment: @Stataq Just do `df$data <- gsub('data','',df$data)` in a new line of code.

Comment: May I ask what is the difference between `$id` and `.id`. In your codes, `$id is 1, 2, 3` and `.id='data' created var data with value data1, data2,...` . Why we need to create `$id`?

Comment: @Stataq It is a may how functions work, dont be confused by that!